# Find the occurences of a substring in string using php?

Tags: php, string, substr

I need to count the number of occurences of the substring in a string.

my code like,

```
$str1 = "when he arrives, he want to open the door.";
$find_str = "he";
```

here the string "he" is occured 4 times.

how can i find it in php?..

Comment: I have tried by using preg_match_all(); but its not worked fine..

Comment: see the answer, but please: Next time please google this first. It is really not hard to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php):

```
substr_count($str1, $find_str)
```

Answer (score 3):

Make use of the [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) php function.

**Solution:**

```
$str1 = "when he arrives, he want to open the door.";
$find_str = "he";

substr_count($str1, $find_str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo substr_count($str1, $find_str);
```